# Script to parse emails for attachments

Tags: php, linux, bash, email, attachment

I am looking for a way to monitor a Linux mbox email account, when an email arrives I would like to download an attachment from the email and save the attachment (CSV file) so that it may be used by a PHP script. What would be the best way of going about this? I have looked at PHP's IMAP functions but this does not appear to be the most appropriate method when a simple bash script may be all that is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this situation I pipe the email to a PHP script and let the PHP script parse the email. You get instant results versus waiting for a cronjob to pull emails down

```
$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
while (!feof($stdin))
{
$input .= fread($stdin, 8192);
}
```

now you have the entire email in `$input` and you can use the boundries to extract the base64 encoded information and then `file_put_contents("/tmp/file.csv",base64_decode($extracted_file_contents))`

make sure you chmod +x

Comment: Thanks, this looks perfect - when you say pipe the email, do you have a particular method, do you amend the mailbox settings somehow to call a script, my server runs Plesk so the mailbox is handled by qmail?

Comment: I use this with qmail - you just have to add a .qmail file to the user directory and put in |/var/www/htdocs/script.php

Comment: If you don't have CLI access there should be a way in plesk to forward emails to a script